# Specialice template function

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following template to store simplified SI units:

```
template < int Mass, int Length, int Time >
class TUnit
{
public:
    // Used type.
typedef float DataType;
    .....
}
```

For example SI Unit "length" is defined as follows:

```
typedef TUnit< 0, 1, 0 > Length;
```

There exits a global generic function to convert DataTypes to TUnits:

```
template < int Mass, int Length, int Time >
TUnit< Mass, Length, Time > convert( const typename TUnit< Mass, Length, Time >::DataType& src );
```

And we have a specialized version to convert float to length with e.g. an implicit conversion e.g. from [km] to [m]:

```
template < >
Tools::DataTypes::Length convert( const Tools::DataTypes::Length::DataType& src );
```

Now try to convert a float to length:

```
float f = 1.0;
Length l = ::convert( f )
```

Now VC2012 fails to compile with error code:

```
error C2783: could not deduce template argument for 'Mass'
             could not deduce template argument for 'Length'
             could not deduce template argument for 'Time'
```

To solve this I changed the code to:

```
float f = 1.0;
Length l = ::convert< 0, 1, 0 >( f )
```

Nice but this is not what I want :) My preferred syntax would be:

```
float f = 1.0;
Length l = ::convert< Length >( f )
```

I think I have to change the signature of the generic template function to something like this:

```
template < TUnit< int Mass, int Length, int Time > >
TUnit< Mass, Length, Time > convert( const typename TUnit< Mass, Length, Time >::DataType& src );
```

But of course this syntax is wrong. Any hints to solve this ?

Comment: Doesn't Boost.Units already do all of that?

Comment: Yes but boost::units is oversized for my problem and I did not find a solution within the boost code.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Variant (via template class)

You can not specialize function templates. If you really want to do this, then make a class with a single static function and specialize that class. You can then make the function call the static method of that class.

```
template < int Mass, int Length, int Time >
TUnit< Mass, Length, Time > convert( const typename TUnit< Mass, Length, Time >::DataType& src ) {
  return Converter<Mass, Length, Time>::call();
}
```

And then you define the template class:

```
template < int Mass, int Length, int Time >
struct Converter {
   static TUnit< Mass, Length, Time > call( const typename TUnit< Mass, Length, Time >::DataType& src) {
     [...]
   }
};
```

And its specializations, e.g. for Length:

```
template < >
struct Converter<0,1,0> {
   static const int Mass = 0;
   static const int Length = 1;
   static const int Time = 0;

   static TUnit< Mass, Length, Time > call( const typename TUnit< Mass, Length, Time >::DataType& src) {
     [...]
   }
};
```

### 2. Variant Overloading

Alternatively, I would recommend to use function overloading instead, which will mostly be equivalent, with that I mean

```
// NOTE: no `template < >`
Tools::DataTypes::Length convert( const Tools::DataTypes::Length::DataType& src );
```

Due to the C++ overload mechanism this overloaded function has precedence over the function template `convert<Mass, Length, Time>`. That is as long as you don't call the function with explicit template arguments.

### 3. Variant Additional Function Template

If you want to your second approach to work, then I recommend:

```
template < int Mass_, int Length_, int Time_ >
class TUnit
{
public:
  static const int Mass = Mass_;
  static const int Length = Length_;
  static const int Time = Time_;
[...]
```

And then

```
template < class TUnitT >
TUnitT convert( const typename TUnitT::DataType& src ) {
  return convert<TUnitT::Mass, TUnitT::Length, TUnitT::Time>(src);
}
```

But I would recommend the first approach.

Comment: Hm...ok the first approach fails as soon as a second convert function is available e.g. for Mass because only the return type differs. The second approach seems to equal to Nicks one ?

Comment: Well my first approach are actually two possibilities. Simple overlaoding, what I call "Alternatively" will fail. But I also start to see that what you are up to is a bit more tricky than I thought.

Comment: Ok, I expanded my answer in particular the 1. Variant, which I now think is what most models what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use a template as a template argument. In this case it will be a specialized type so you don't even have to use the template template idiom. Just write something like this:

```
template < class TUNIT>
TUNIT convert( const typename TUNIT::DataType& src );

template < int M, int A, int B>
TUnit<M,A,B> convert( const typename TUnit<M,A,B>::DataType& src )
{
    typedef TUnit< M,A,B > TUnit_;
    return ::convert<TUnit_>(src);
}

...

typedef TUnit< 0, 1, 0 > Length;

...

float f = 1.0f;
Length l = ::convert< Length >( f );
```

This will compile fine.

Comment: Yes for sure. But convert does now match for every type.

Comment: Why not? (I assume you meant "does not match for ...")

Comment: Because the conversation can (shall) only be valid for TUnit types.

Comment: You can do it both ways, see the EDIT.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your example. In each case you define a common convert function usable for ANY type. This is not expected.

Comment: The signature matches any type yes, but I imagine that the function implementation uses specific members of TUnit. So other types just won't compile.   

From what I understood you wanted to be able to use convert with either TUnit or the 3 integers, the first definition works for the former, and the second one is a wrapper for the latter.